# CRUD logic in Controller or Block?

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, crud

I have referred several blogs which explains **CRUD** functionality, some of the blogs write code like saving a model, in a Controller and some in a Block.

Blogs CRUD functionality in Block :

> http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/
>   http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2016/04/04/magento2-crud-module-development-series-part3/

Blogs CRUD functionality in Controller :

> https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-5-adminhtml/
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988661/magento-2-insert-data-into-database

I am bit confused which Magento 2 standard should I adopt?

I use Magento **Version 2.1.7.**

Answer (score 0):

All the CRUD Functionalities should be performed via Repository or Models which is the Magento Standard. In all the examples you have provided, Blocks and Controllers are not directly accessing the tables.

Here, Blocks and Controllers uses Models and Resource Models to perform the CRUD Operation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I know that Magento uses Model and Resource Model to perform the CRUD operation. Need to know place where I will write business logic?